# set height of button in spark ButtonBar flex4

Tags: apache-flex, button, height, buttonbar

i have the following code:

```
        <s:ButtonBar id="tabs" y="15" left="0" height="31"
                 change="VideosMenuBar_changeHandler(event)" requireSelection="true">  
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout gap="1" columnWidth="180" variableColumnWidth="false"   
                                />
        </s:layout>

        <s:ArrayCollection>
            <fx:String>Latest Videos</fx:String>
            <fx:String>Last Week Videos</fx:String>
            <fx:String>Last Month Videos</fx:String>
        </s:ArrayCollection>

    </s:ButtonBar>
```

how can i change the height of the buttons in this buttonbar?? is it possible without extra skin class??

Comment: Have you tried `<s:HorizontalLayout verticalAlign="justify" ...` ?

Comment: Isn't `height="31"` working for you?

Comment: Thanks Maxim you solved my problem! awq height="31" expands the whole area of the buttonbar but the buttons remain small

Answer (score 3):

i solved the problem with the answer of Maxim Kachurovskiy given above by putting

```
<s:HorizontalLayout verticalAlign="justify" .../>
```